# How can I copy a file of a certain extension or containing a certain phrase/pattern in R?

Tags: r

I'm developing a For loop to copy a specific file from one directory and paste it into another, and then rename it. The code itself is fairly solid, as it was developed to be used previously to do the same thing, but for a different file.

My issue is that the file I want has had different naming conventions in the past, making it more difficult than just copying and renaming every file with one name.

Notably, all files possess the same "pattern" of '_descriptor.xml' at the end -- the bit that has changed is in the beginning, which is generally 9 characters (but not always). Is there a clean way to tell R to copy files that have this pattern?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pattern` argument in `list.files` to select files that have specific pattern in them.

```
files_to_copy <- list.files(pattern = '_descriptor\\.xml$', full.names = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

We can also do

```
files_to_copy <- list.files(pattern = '_descriptor[.]xml$', full.names = TRUE)
```